# about proving a sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis

Consider this sequence {$x_n$}.

$x_n=\frac{1}{2^{2^{n}}}$ for $n=1,2,...$.

Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x_n=0$.

Proof: Fix $\epsilon>0$, we have $d(x_n,0)=|x_n-0|=\frac{1}{2^{2^{n}}}$.
So it is enough that $\frac{1}{2^{2^{n}}}<\epsilon$ or equivalently $n>log_{2}(log_{2}(\frac{1}{\epsilon }))$. We konw that for all $n>N$, $d(x_n,0)<\epsilon$.

This finishes the proof.

But here is a problem and actually my question is what about if $log_{2}(\frac{1}{\epsilon })<0$? so $n$ is then meaningless and it's like this does not hold for all $\epsilon >0$.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider the inequality $ \frac{1}{2^{2^{n}}} <\frac{1}{n} $. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213298/prove-that-the-sequence-n2-3n2-1-converges-to-the-limit-0/213321#213321) for a related problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about $\log_2(1/\epsilon)$ being negative, then just make sure $1/\epsilon>1$, i.e. $\epsilon<1$.  Most people would accept "without loss of generality, take $\epsilon<1$", but to be proper you might consider $\epsilon\geq 1$ separately, i.e. pick a different $N$ for that case (you'll find it easy to choose an $N$ that works for every $\epsilon\geq 1$...)