# How can I prove that a sequence has a given limit?

Tags: limits

For example, let's say that I have some sequence $$\left\{c_n\right\} = \left\{\frac{n^2 + 10}{2n^2}\right\}$$ How can I prove that $\{c_n\}$ approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

I'm using the Buchanan textbook, but I'm not understanding their proofs at all.

Comment: A related [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213298/prove-that-the-sequence-n2-3n2-1-converges-to-the-limit-0/213321#213321).

Comment: You need to separate intuition from the formal proof. The expression above simplifies to $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{n^2}$. You can see that as $n$ gets larger and larger, the term $\frac{5}{n^2}$ gets smaller and smaller; in fact, as small as you want (other than zero). Hence intuitively, you should see (hopefully) that the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well we want to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|c_n-1/2|<\epsilon$ (this is the definition of a limit). In this case we are looking for a natural number $N$ such that if $n>N$ then
$$\left|\frac{n^2+10}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\frac{5}{n^2}<\epsilon$$
We can make use of what's called the *Archimedean property*, which is that for any real number $x$ there is a natural number larger than it. To do so, note that the above equation is equivalent to $\frac{n^2}{5}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, or $n^2>\frac{5}{\epsilon}$. If we choose $N$ to be a natural number greater than $\frac{5}{\epsilon}$, then if $n>N$ we have $n^2>N>\frac{5}{\epsilon}$ as desired. Thus $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n = \frac12$.

To relate this to the definition of limit in Buchanan: You want to show that for any neighborhood of $1/2$, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that if $n>N$ then $c_n$ is in the neighborhood. Now note that any neighborhood contains an *open interval* around $1/2$, which takes the form $(1/2-\epsilon,1/2+\epsilon)$. Saying that $c_n$ is in this open interval is the same as saying that $|c_n-1/2|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Okay, whoa, I'm sorry — this went *way* over my head.

Comment: @tekknolagi Have you seen limits formally defined before?

Comment: I have not; they're defined in Ch 2.6 in words, and in terms of a "game" played by two people: http://www.paly.net/teachers/santink/AnalysisDocs/BuchananLimitsExcerpt/Buchannan%20Limits%20Text%20ch%202%20and%206%20and%20answers.pdf

Comment: @tekknolagi    Yes, in the text, they have defined formally. And this is the proof you need.

Comment: @tekknolagi Well you can't prove anything without a formal definition. But the page you mention has a formal definition (see the paragraph under "Definition of Convergence", recalling that convergence means having a limit).

Comment: @tekknolagi I've edited the post to relate it to your definition of limit.

Comment: I think the way most textbooks define it is actually more confusing, and leads to more false notions of the nature of limits, than the simple statement $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = L \Leftrightarrow \forall \; \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \; N \in \mathbb{N} \ni n > N \Rightarrow \left|a_n-L\right|<\varepsilon$$

Comment: Okay that just made a lot more sense. Thank you, Alex! I'll look this over.

Comment: @AJMansfield Some of your symbols seem off, and you have some backwards arrows.

Comment: @AlexBecker I was having browser trouble when I entered it, I have corrected it.

Comment: @AJMansfield Also may I add that while that is clear and understandable to you or me, it seems like quite the incomprehensible jumble of symbols to most novices.

Comment: @AlexBecker Not once you teach them how to read it.  I still find it frustrating how my calculus teacher uses all these clunky, imprecise, not-entirely-correct definitions of all the stuff rather than just teaching the class how to actually read the symbols, which would be more useful to them anyway.

Comment: @AJMansfield It is quite possible to define limits correctly without using these symbols. For example, the definition in Buchanan is 100% correct and precise, and is in fact more general (as it extends to topological spaces), although it requires the definition of neighborhood.

Comment: @AlexBecker I guess you're right, but it's still irritating.

Answer (score 4):

You need to show that for any number $\epsilon>0$ you can find $N$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $|c_n - \frac{1}{2}| < \epsilon$.

So, pick an $\epsilon>0$ and start computing: $|c_n - \frac{1}{2}| = | \frac{n^2+10}{2 n^2} - \frac{1}{2}| = |\frac{10}{2 n^2}| = \frac{5}{n^2}$.

Now you need to pick $N$ such that if $n \geq N$, then $\frac{5}{n^2} < \epsilon$. If I pick $N \geq \sqrt{\frac{5}{\epsilon}}+1$, then you can see that if $n \geq N$, then $\frac{5}{n^2} < \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, you are finished.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {n^2+10}{2n^2} = \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \frac {1+\frac {10}{n^2}}{2} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left (\frac 12+\frac{10}{2n^2} \right) = \frac 12+5\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac 1{n^2}=\frac 12
$$

Comment: While this is certainly valid, I believe my teacher's intent on doing something with inequalities.

Comment: Usually inequalities are used to find some "simple" limits, and then using that "simple" limits and limit properties people find some more complex ones.

Comment: Hmm. If you see the text we're studying now ( http://www.paly.net/teachers/santink/AnalysisDocs/BuchananLimitsExcerpt/Buchannan%20Limits%20Text%20ch%202%20and%206%20and%20answers.pdf ), in Ch 2.6 (p35) the text goes into detail with inequalities and more complex limits; I simply did not understand Buchanan's method of proof.

Comment: He needs an episilon-delta proof not one using properties of limits.

Comment: @tekknolagi you can prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac 1n = 0$ using epsilon, and then use properties of limits to prove whatever you wanna prove.

Answer (score 1):

In general, we say that a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ if $|x_n - x| \rightarrow 0$. This means that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$.

We can also use results about sequences that will be proved in any good introductory texts, such as if $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$:

$i) x_n + y_n \rightarrow x+y$

$ii) x_ny_n \rightarrow xy$

$iii)\lambda x_n \rightarrow \lambda x$

$iv)$ If $x \not= 0$ then  $\frac{y_n}{x_n} \rightarrow \frac{y}{x}$

Using these results we can see that $\displaystyle c_n = \frac{n^2 + 10}{2n^2} = \frac{1+\frac{10}{n^2}}{2}$. So if $a_n = \frac{10}{n^2} \rightarrow a$ then $c_n \rightarrow \frac{1+a}{2}$. Now we can prove that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ using epsilon delta techniques, so it follows that $c_n \rightarrow \frac12$.