# Basic real analysis question on the epsilon-delta format

Tags: real-analysis

Oftentimes when you hear about "how to prove" that a specific sequence or function is converging to a specific value, people will refer to the epsilon-delta style. While I have no question about the validity of such a style, I do not see that way eye to eye as intuitive or clean.

For example, we know that the sequence $\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ converges to 0 when $n$ gets very large. But when asked to formally prove this epsilon-delta style, I draw a blank and refer immediately to a procedural technique without really understanding the problem or the procedure. I can start with : "Let $\epsilon > 0$, then there is an $n$ s.t $n > N$. We want to show that $\frac{n}{n^2+1} < \epsilon$."

My question here is why do we want to find an $n > N$ and how to find that $N$? (I know that $\frac{n}{n^2+1} < n$) And after I found this $N$ and use the epsilon-delta format what does this argument even mean?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213298/prove-that-the-sequence-n2-3n2-1-converges-to-the-limit-0/213321#213321).

Comment: You mean $\frac{n}{n^2+1}<\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: In my opinion, the $\epsilon$-$N$ argument adds **nothing** to the intuition about the long-term behaviour of $\frac{n}{n^2+1}$. (And an hour or so ago, I wrote an $\epsilon$-$N$ argument for precisely this sequence!) What it is is an *exercise* in using the $\epsilon$-$N$ language, which can be very important in more complex situations. It is analogous to learning certain words in a new language by using them in sentences.

Comment: I think it is confusing to refer to "epsilon-delta" (or epsilon-N) as a _style_ of proof.  The kind of proof that this usually refers to is a straightforward verification that the definition of convergence applies.  You may not think that the definition of convergence is "intuitive" or "clean", but given that the definition is what it is, there is an obvious way to go about verifying it in any particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct to begin the problem by precisely stating the definition of the limit is good, but you misstated it.  What you want is:

> Let $\epsilon > 0$.  We want to find $N > 0$ such that if $n > N$, then $\dfrac{n}{n^2 + 1} < \epsilon$.

Note that in your original statement you hadn't even defined $N$ before putting it to use, and you also said "there exists $n > N$", which seems to state that some $n$ exists larger than $N$ with some property, which is different from the correct condition that *all* $n > N$ have that property.

Anyway, once you've sorted out the language you have only to figure out how large to make $n$ such that $n/(n^2 + 1)$ is sufficiently small.  This is not usually just a matter of manipulating the fraction, but also applying some simplifying inequalities.  For example,
$$\frac{n}{n^2 + 1} < \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n},$$
so it's enough to find $N$ such that for $n > N$, we have $1/n < \epsilon$.  This latter inequality is equivalent to $n > 1/\epsilon$, so we can take $N$ to be any integer larger than $1/\epsilon$.

This is the "discovery" version of the proof.  The "direct" formulation just avoids the process of figuring out $N$ and uses the correct value from the start.  That is: you say that given $\epsilon > 0$, define $N$ such that $N \geq 1/\epsilon$, so that if $n > N$, we have
$$\frac{n}{n^2 + 1} < \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} \leq \frac{1}{1/\epsilon} = \epsilon,$$
as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote your sequence by $a_n$ so if we prove that for every $\epsilon $ we find  $N$ and if $n> N$ then $|a_n|<\epsilon$ this means that all the terms of this sequence from the term $a_N$ are close to $0$ with distance lower than $\epsilon $ so the terms accumulate at zero and this explains the definition of the limit.

Comment: Have a great slumber my brother in Heaven. :+)