# Using only the limit definition, prove that the sequence $\frac{n^3 + n}{2n^3+1}$ con- verges

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I am self studying Understanding Analysis, and I was trying to do the following problem:

> Using only the limit definition, prove that the sequence $\frac{n^3 + n}{2n^3+1}$ con-
> verges.

I know the sequence should converge to 1/2 (from calculus), but I'm lost on how to prove it. I am trying to do something similar this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/213321/688643).

Since I know the sequence converges to 1/2, I tried: $$\lvert \frac{n^3 + n}{2n^3+1} - \frac{1}{2}\rvert < \epsilon$$
then
$$\lvert \frac{2n-1}{4n^3+2} \rvert < \epsilon$$
$$\lvert \frac{2n-1}{4n^3+2} \rvert < \lvert \frac{2n-1}{4n^2-1} \rvert =  \frac{1}{2n+1}  < \epsilon$$
$$n > (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1)$$

So if we choose $N > (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1)$, for any n>N, we have:
$$\lvert \frac{2n-1}{4n^3+2} \rvert < \frac{1}{2n+1} < \epsilon$$

I'm pretty sure the solution is wrong, since we should be saying the fraction is smaller than $\lvert \frac{2n-1}{4n^3+2}\rvert$ for the inequality to hold.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. You have correctly proved the implication you wanted by using proper bounds.

Comment: If you observe that $4n^{3}+2>4n^{2}>4n^{2}-1$ then everything would be fine.

Comment: The thing I do not understand is how come we can say something is larger than $x_n$ but smaller than $\epsilon$, shouldn't we be going the other way around? In other words, shouldn't we try to come up with a term that is smaller than $x_n$?